# Error when I use an expression in Report Designer - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, string-concatenation

In Report Designer of VS 2010, I have designed a local report (.rdlc) in a ASP.NET web application. In this report, I can display fields of dataset (example:

`=Fields!CONTRACT_NO.Value), constants, expressions with constants (="One" & " Two")`,

but when I try to concatenate a field with a string

```
(="Number " & Fields!AC_TYPE.Value),
```

this field display in report: #Error.

I try to explicitly convert the field to string: `="Number " & CStr(Fields!AC_TYPE.Value)`

, but I have the same error.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For Concatenation Purpose You Can use `+` symbol instead of  `&`

For Eg:

```
=IIf(Fields!Itemamount.Value<0,"("+""+Format(Abs(Fields!Itemamount.Value),"N")+""+")",Format(Fields!Itemamount.Value,"N"))
```

like this.